# Incorrect syntax near @ fileid

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to all the sql function from the c#.
I've had added the parameters to the function as @ fileid and useid. But getting an error. I couldn't figure out the bug in my code..

```
string query = "exec fn_sh_HitInfo(@fileid,@UserID)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fileid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value=fid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value =UserID;
        string taglist = string.Empty;


        try
        {
            taglist = DBAction.ExecuteQuery(cmd, FilteringControl.ProjectID).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: So whats the error you're getting?

Comment: @Paul0712 - It's in the title.

Comment: syntax error near @ fileid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use parentheses

```
exec fn_sh_GetTagListHitInfo @fileid,@UserID
```

Or if this is a scalar UDF you can alternatively use `SELECT` instead of `EXEC` (requires schema name in this case)

```
SELECT dbo.fn_sh_GetTagListHitInfo (@fileid,@UserID )
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `exec` part and you don't need to know the correct syntax.

```
    //string query = "exec fn_sh_GetTagListHitInfo(@fileid,@UserID)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();     
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;      // just mark it as an SP
    cmd.CommandText = "fn_sh_GetTagListHitInfo";        // only the name
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fileid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value=fid;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = FilteringControl.UserID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the cmd.CommandText value and try.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select fn_sh_GetTagListHitInfo(@fileid,@UserID)";
```